# v-show doesn't work when using vuex getter in computed property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuejs3

In Template

```
<LeaderboardChart v-show="leaderboardNotEmpty"/>
```

The computed property

```
computed: {
    leaderboardNotEmpty(){
        console.log(this.$store.getters.getLeaderboard.length > 0)
        return this.$store.getters.getLeaderboard.length > 0
    }
}
```

The console.log returns true but the v-show still returns display: none. I would like to understand why

Edit:
I found the error. Another completely different component threw an error and canceled the complete render process from vue. Found it by commenting out all other components.

Comment: what about printing it inside the template like `{{leaderboardNotEmpty}}`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim then it also shows true

Comment: what about `v-if` instead of `v-show`? or are you using other style to define the display?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim v-if also doesn't work. Also other div containers don't work too. No additional styles used. When I use v-show="true" it works. But not with the computed property.

Comment: If `leaderboardNotEmpty` is TRUE even when `getLeaderboard` has no elements inside - try to move the comparison inside the getter, i.e. convert the computed property into another Vuex getter.

Comment: @IVOGELOV leaderboardNotEmpty is false when no elements are inside. It also returns true correctly when elements are inside. When I'm at home I will try to write another getter in the store

Comment: If the computed property returns the correct value at all times - then `v-if` will work at all times. If it does not - then the computed property returns wrong data.

Comment: @IVOGELOV This is the weird part. I checked with console.log() and I check with {{leaderboardNotEmpty}} and both return true at the right time. But v-show still displays none

Comment: If the template prints `true` for `{{leaderboardNotEmpty}}` the error is in your template, not in the computed. It might be invalid syntax, a typo or a layout logic bug. We can't help you solve a problem you're not showing. Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve], **making sure** the error is repro-ed. In the example, you can replace the computed with `{ return true }`. I guarantee the bug is not related to the store, since you're seeing its value printed as `true` in template.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys. I found the error and updated my question

Comment: Are you saying that there was no red text in the browser console at the time you're checking the `v-show`? Because if there was - it should have warned you that you first need to fix **that** error before debugging why `v-show` does not work ...